# How to execute a parameter if a condition is validated

Tags: pine-script

Why this Condition does not work:
I want once the condition is validated to execute the parameter just below

```
if rsi >= 70
band0 = plot(100, title="Uppery
band1 = plot(70, title="Lower Line 70",style=plot.style_line, linewidth=3, color=green)

if rsi <= 30

band2 = plot(0, title="Lower Line 0",style=plot.style_line, linewidth=3, color=red)
band3 = plot(30, title="Lower Line 30",style=plot.style_line, linewidth=3, color=red)
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen? Can you attach a drawing? Also you must pay attention to indentation in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if` require indentation, also you can't use `plot` locally, you can eventually use:

```
band0 = plot(100, title="Uppery",color=rsi >= 70 ? color.blue : na)
band1 = plot(70, title="Lower Line 70",style=plot.style_line, linewidth=3, color=rsi >= 70 ? color.green : an)

band2 = plot(0, title="Lower Line 0",style=plot.style_line, linewidth=3, color=rsi <= 30 ? color.red : na)
band3 = plot(30, title="Lower Line 30",style=plot.style_line, linewidth=3, color=rsi <= 30 ? color.red : na)
```